# itextsharp unexpected errors

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am new in using this library and I found several examples (I am splitting PDF by page):

- [code source 1](http://www.jamesewelch.com/2008/11/14/how-to-extract-pages-from-a-pdf-document/)
- [code source 2](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2006/10/11/burstcs-split-a-pdf-in-several-separate-pdf-files-1-per-page/)
- [code source 3](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/0596527543/working-with-code-libraries/windowsdpt-chp-4-sect-12)

But always when somebody begin use `Filestream` errors occurs `(Object reference not ...)`. While creating `Filestream` no one error occurs. Whats wrong? Library I have downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

**EDIT**

```
   private static void Test()
    {
        Document pdfDocument = new Document( );
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument,
        new FileStream("D:\\WDPT.PDF", FileMode.Create));
        // here is eror
        pdfDocument.Open( );
        pdfDocument.Add(new Paragraph("Here is a test of creating a PDF"));
        pdfDocument.Close( );
    }
```

This code is runned in console application.The eror here occurs when we begin using filestream (as in other cases).

Comment: show your code. the examples are not relevant in solving your problem

Comment: Does WDPT.pdf exist on your machine at this location?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you must use the object writer,

```
            Document pdfDocument= new Document(PageSize.A4);

            new PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream(OutPutFileNameFullPath+ ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

            pdfDocument.Open();
            pdfDocument.Add(new Paragraph("Here is a test of creating a PDF"));
            pdfDocument.Close( );
```

Comment: If you don't use the `PdfWriter` instance later on, you do not need to put it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this to use DLL reference(here is code of VB)

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser
Imports iTextSharp.text.html
```

Then pass your stream object to generate PDF.

If you got error: "object reference set is not to an instance of an object" i.e. somewhere
After declaration you set it null(or it would be pass as null).
Write code as below

```
    Dim pDoc As New Document(pRec)
    Dim pWriter As PdfWriter
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Title & " .pdf")
    pWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pDoc, Response.OutputStream)
    pRec.Border = 1
    pRec.BorderColor = BaseColor.MAGENTA
    pDoc.Open()
    'Add pdf Detail
    pDoc.AddTitle("REPORTS")
    pDoc.AddSubject(Title)
    pDoc.AddAuthor("ADMIN")
    pDoc.AddHeader("Company", "DK LTD")
    pDoc.AddHeader("PageSize", DocSize)
```

Add your stream writer object here,
then looping till EOF
then

```
   pdoc.close()
```

I'll try to explain best of what I know.